# DB update query in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update the `hours_worked` column in `daiy_attendance` table using `in_time` and `out_time` in same table. `in_time` and `out_time` already stored in the table.

So I'm using `timediff` to get the difference. Query runs and execute correctly when I try it on the `phpmyadmin` sql format, but when I try to run it in the program it does not update the `hours_worked` column. It does not gives any errors.

```
$sql5 = "UPDATE daily_attendances SET hours_worked = TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time) WHERE in_time != '' AND out_time != '' ";
$result2 = DB::statement(DB::raw($sql5));
```

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant: did you set 'time_worked' as fillable?

Comment: @JohnDoe it is nullable

Comment: @JohnDoe OP is not using a model, so `$fillable` attributes are irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnDoe yes i have added

Comment: put your query in `try.. catch()` block and see if there is any error..

Answer (score 4):

try

```
DB::table('daily_attendances')
                ->whereRaw("in_time != '' AND out_time != ''")
                ->update(['hours_worked ' =>DB::raw('TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time)')]);
```

OR 
JUST use `db:statement`

```
$sql5 = "UPDATE daily_attendances SET hours_worked = TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time) WHERE in_time != '' AND out_time != '' ";
$result2 = DB::statement($sql5);
```

Comment: Check  your database connection , is it connecting to same database that you tried from phpmyadmin

Comment: connection is fine